# How to determine maximum supply voltage of a circuit

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors

I am working on a small electronic device. I am trying to find the maximum supply voltage I can inject into the circuit before damaging one or multiple components.

The circuit (in CEI) is the following:

[image]

Both resistors have a maximum dissipation power of 2/3 W. Both LEDs are 2.6 V @ 20 mA.The IC 74LS00N has a maximum supply voltage of 5.25 V according to its datasheet.

To calculate the theoretical max. Vcc, I am at a loss on the procedure to follow.

I calculated the maximum voltage that could be applied on the resistors with the formula P = U × I by taking I = 20 mA since the LEDs can't support more. I obtained 33.33 V.

After that, I don't know what to do.

Could someone explain a method to resolve this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You have an LS chip. It has a maximum of 5.25V, which means you need 5.0V supply that is with 5% tolerance over all usage conditions. There is no other VCC you can use because the chip output needs to control the LEDs.

The LS chip also has a maximum input voltage of 7V. Usually, you don't apply more than the supply voltage it has. The input also draws some current so how much resistance there is in series must be carefully selected to be low enough.

The LS chip also can't have the outputs pulled higher than supply or lower than ground.

So whatever you are doing, both the chip and all it's inputs and outputs must preferably be within chip supply volage.

Comment: I may have done a mistake by not providing the whole circuit. Considering that there is a potentiometer in serie with a resistor before the IC. Should I take into account the drops of voltage of both and add it to the 5.25V to obtain the true value I can supply to the circuit?

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much for your answer.